# split distinct words in a rich text box

Tags: vb.net

i have been trying to display the number of distinct words in a rich text box.i have tried every way but it's still the same.Kindly help.thanks

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\FOR\testit.txt"   'read file from an existing folder in the computer
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then 'check if file exists
            Dim fReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            RichTextBox2.Text = fReader.ReadToEnd 'read the file into the rich text box to the end
            fReader.Close()
        Else : MsgBox("No such file exists") 'if the file doesnt exist, prompt a msg box that no such file exists
        End If

        Dim newWords As String
        newWords = RichTextBox2.Text
        Dim word1 As Array
        word1 = newWords.Split(" ")
        Dim counter = 0
        Dim input As Array = word1
        Dim check As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        For Each p As String In input
            If Not check.ContainsKey(p) Then
                check.Add(p, 0)
                counter = counter + 1  'count distinct words in an array

            End If
            Label4.Text = counter 'display number of distinct words in label4
            check(p) += 1

        Next
```

Comment: What/Where is your problem?

Comment: well, i'm sorry if i did not tag my question correctly.i'm new here.i cant seem to split the words.the words are still joined together and it takes forever to count the words

Comment: For the most part, your code works.  You should be careful though since spaces aren't probably your only splitter, the line break characters are probably involved, too.  Test on a smaller sample size, and if you still have problems, post the contents of the small sample file.  Your dictionary should be `(Of String, Integer)`.

Comment: i have tried it again and removed all the line breaks.this is the content.--- The door is locked then my friend said Mr Lorry surprised

Ay Yes was the grim reply of Monsieur Defarge

You think it necessary to keep the unfortunate gentleman so retired

I think it necessary to turn the key Monsieur Defarge whispered it
closer in his ear and frowned heavily

Why

Why Because he has lived so long locked up that he would be
frightenedravetear himself to piecesdiecome to I know not what
harmif his door was left open

Is it possible exclaimed Mr Lorry

Is it possible repeated Defarge bitterly

Comment: i read the file from a folder and still experiencing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just do this:

```
    Label4.Text =
        RichTextBox2 _
            .Text _
            .Split(" ") _
            .ToLookup(Function(x) x) _
            .Count()
```